# mysql use result from select as where clause in UNION query

Tags: mysql

I have table A whit this columns:

```
id   name      to_include
1    wanted1   null
2    wanted2   wanted1
```

If the query is for wanted2 then I need a way to use the value from **to_include** column (in this case **wanted1**) in the WHERE clause 
I have tried some like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM A WHERE name = 'wanted2'
) AS B
UNION
SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.name = B.to_include
```

That got this error:
*Unknown column 'B.to_include' in 'where clause*

**Expected result:**
A recordset with both two rows from the example table.

Comment: You want to use either a JOIN  or IN or EXISTS not a UNION

Comment: I think both is needed - UNION **and** JOIN. But the question isn't really clear.

Comment: Post what the result should look like, it's hard to tell from your description. I suspect @PaulSpiegel is right -- you need a `JOIN` in one query and then combine that with `UNION`.

Comment: Expected result: A recordset with both two rows from the example table.

Comment: What if there is a third row (`3, 'wanted3', 'wanted2'`) and the query is "for wanted3". What result would you expect?

Comment: In that case expected : row 3 And row 2

Comment: Then you should be fine with Barmars answer. I was afraid, you would need  to "include" the rows recursively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't refer to a previous query in a `UNION` as an alias. Each query in the `UNION` is processed independently, then the results are combined.

The second query in the `UNION` needs to be a `JOIN`, and you need to repeat the criteria from the first query when you do this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourTable WHERE name = 'wanted2'

UNION

SELECT b.*
FROM yourTable AS a
JOIN yourTable AS b ON b.name = a.to_include
WHERE a.name = 'wanted2'
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28d72/1)

Comment: Depending on data it's also possible to use only the second part with `ON b.name IN (a.name, a.to_include)`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yeah, that works, but this code expresses the intent more clearly, IMHO.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I have tested your version and yes that work also, but what you mean with "_Depending on data_"?

Comment: @MTK If `name` is not UNIQUE you might get a different result (creating duplicates). Here's an exmple: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02820/1

Comment: @PaulSpigel. Thank's. Is good for me to know that. I try to learn by little steps.